# WordPress recoger datos en frontend desde input de plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de un plugin para wordpress. El plugin es para mostrar un slider en el front, desde los ajustes del plugin en el backoffice podemos establecer la url de la imagen, título, subtitulo...

[image: BackOffice del plugin]

En el front tengo el slider correctamente renderizado.

[image: Slider en el frontEnd]

en el archivo principal del plugin encolo los estilos css propios, el js propio, bootstrap... También creo el menú del backoffice y hago el enlace al archivo en el que maqueté el backoffice (otro archivo) y al archivo en el que maqueté el slider (otro archivo) la maquetación del slider básicamente va en un función la cual tiene hook en generate_after_header por lo tanto, siempre me pinta el slider después del header.
Ahora mismo tengo las fotos y texto hardcodeados, el problema es que quiero meter los datos desde los inputs del backoffice pero no lo logro.

En el backoffice tengo el form con method post y action front-content.php para que al hacer el submit lleve esos datos al archivo del front.

en el archivo del front, creeé una variable para recoger uno de los datos que envío por post.

Cuando desde el backoffice agrego un título y pulso el botón de envíar, la página del backoofice cambia y se agrega la página del front a la url y efectivamente veo el dato introducido...

Pero la idea es poder ver esto desde el front (desde el cual no me reconoce la variable)

**gestion-web.php** archivo principal del plugin

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Gestion web
 * Plugin URI: https://www.altia.es/es/altia
 * Description: Plugin para gestionar la home de sitios WordPress
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Adrián Fraga Cortés
 * Author URI: https://www.altia.es/es/altia
 * License: GPLv2
*/

//ACTIVAR Y DESACTIVAR PLUGIN

function activate(){
    
}

function deactivate(){

}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate');
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate');

//AGREGAR MENU DE ADMINISTRADOR

function createMenu(){
    add_menu_page(
        'Gestión web',                                    //Título de la página
        'Gestión web',                                    //Título del menú
        'manage_options',                                 //Permiso de administrador
        'gw_menu',                                        //Slug
        'requireContent',                                 //Función del contenido, llama al archivo del backOffice
         plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/img/icon.png',        //Icono
        '1'                                               //Posición menú
    );
}

function requireContent(){
    require_once 'views/admin-content.php';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'createMenu');

//LLAMADA A ARCHIVO FRONTEND

include 'views/front-content.php';

//ENCOLAR BOOTSTRAP

function enqueueBootstrapJS($hook){
    // echo "<script>console.log('$hook')</script>";

    // Comprobar si estamos en el hook correspondiente para que cargue el archivo
    if($hook != "toplevel_page_gw_menu"){
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapJs', plugins_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueBootstrapJS');

function enqueueBootstrapCSS($hook){
    
    // Comprobar si estamos en el hook correspondiente para que cargue el archivo
    if($hook != "toplevel_page_gw_menu"){
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapCSS', plugins_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueBootstrapCSS');

//ENCOLAR CSS PROPIO

function enqueueCSS($hook){
    
    // Comprobar si estamos en el hook correspondiente para que cargue el archivo
    if($hook != "toplevel_page_gw_menu"){
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_style('css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueCSS');

//ENCOLAR jS PROPIO

function enqueueJS($hook){
    
    // Comprobar si estamos en el hook correspondiente para que cargue el archivo
    if($hook != "toplevel_page_gw_menu"){
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('js', plugins_url('js/gestion-web.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueJS');
```

?>

**admin-content.php** archivo para el backOffice

```
<div class="container">

<div class="slider-header row">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2">
        <img src="<?php $path = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
                    echo $path ?>../img/icon-header.png" alt="Luckia_logo">
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h1>Gestión Web</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<hr>

<div class="slider-content">

    <h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center m-3">Configuración slider</h2>

    <form method="POST" action="front-content.php" id="slider-form">

        <div class="d-flex">

            <div class="flex-grow-1 m-1 item-slider">

                <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Slider 1</h3>

                <div class="border border-1 rounded highlight-texts">

                    <div class="m-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" for="slider1-titulo">Título</label> <br>
                        <input class="w-100" name="s1" type="text" id="slider1-titulo" placeholder="Título"></input> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="m-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" for="slider1-subtitulo">Subtítulo</label> <br>
                        <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider1-subtitulo" placeholder="Subtítulo"></input> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="m-3">  
                        <label class="fw-bold form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Textos con mayor contraste</label> <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    </div>
                       
                </div>
                
                <div class="m-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="slider1-imagen">Imagen</label> <br>
                    <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider1-imagen" placeholder="Url imagen"></input> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="m-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="slider1-imagen-movil">Imagen móvil</label> <br>
                    <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider1-imagen-movil" placeholder="Url imagen móvil"></input> <br>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="flex-grow-1 m-1 item-slider">

                <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Slider 2</h3>

                <div class="border border-1 rounded highlight-texts">

                    <div class="m-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" for="slider2-titulo">Título</label> <br>
                        <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider2-titulo" placeholder="Título"></input> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="m-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" for="slider2-subtitulo">Subtítulo</label> <br>
                        <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider2-subtitulo" placeholder="Subtítulo"></input> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="m-3 ">  
                        <label class="fw-bold form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Textos con mayor contraste</label> <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="m-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="slider2-imagen">Imagen</label> <br>
                    <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider2-imagen" placeholder="Url imagen"></input> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="m-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="slider2-imagen-movil">Imagen móvil</label> <br>
                    <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider2-imagen-movil" placeholder="Url imagen móvil"></input> <br>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="flex-grow-1 m-1 item-slider">

                <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Slider 3</h3>

                <div class="border border-1 rounded highlight-texts">

                    <div class="m-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" for="slider3-titulo">Título</label> <br>
                        <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider3-titulo" placeholder="Título"></input> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="m-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" for="slider3-subtitulo">Subtítulo</label> <br>
                        <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider3-subtitulo" placeholder="Subtítulo"></input> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="m-3 ">  
                        <label class="fw-bold form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Textos con mayor contraste</label> <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="m-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="slider3-imagen">Imagen</label> <br>
                    <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider3-imagen" placeholder="Url imagen"></input> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="m-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="slider3-imagen-movil">Imagen móvil</label> <br>
                    <input class="w-100" type="text" id="slider3-imagen-movil" placeholder="Url imagen móvil"></input> <br>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
            <button type="submit" form="slider-form" class="w-25 btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>

<hr>
```

**front-content.php** archivo para el frontend

request )
 
 
    ?>

```
    <!-- CARGAR BOOTSTRAP PARA EL FRONTEND ??  YA ESTÁ ENLOCADO, PERO SIN LA CDN NO FUNCIONA -->

    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    </head>
    
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="http://localhost/portugalStage/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/152.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <div class=" highlight-front">
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="http://localhost/portugalStage/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/134.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <div class=" highlight-front">
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="http://localhost/portugalStage/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/133.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <div class=" highlight-front">
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
        
    </div>

<?php
}

add_action('generate_after_header', 'printCarousel');
```

?>

Alguien hizo algo similar? Necesito poder mostrar los inputs en el front. Estoy atascado. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: No es mas fácil crear un custom post type, guardar cada item del carousel y luego llamarlo con un query?

Comment: Hola Jefferson, gracias por tu respuesta. La idea final es hacerlo con custom post types y shortcodes. Hoy estuve intentándolo de la manera que comento en el post primero para ir paso a paso. Mañana investigaré un poco más los cpt a ver si me voy aclarando (soy novato en programación). Con los cpt podría entonces guardar cada input?

Comment: Ok, investiga y luego presiona [edit] para editar tu pregunta, justo ahora es muy amplia asi que es dificil saber como ayudarte, asi que con una idea mas clara es mas facil dar una solucion, lo que debes de saber es que wp funciona un poco diferente y si no usas los metodos correctos puede que tus funciones no hagan exactamente lo que esperas.